# What is wrong with this DateTime string?

Tags: c#, string, datetime

This string is being generated by an application that I'm trying to debug. DateTime.Parse works but DateTime.ParseExact doesn't. Keeps throwing a bad format exception.

```
// test
string dateTimeFormatted = "2014-11-10T14:49:24-06:00";

try
{
    //yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz 2014-11-10T14:49:24-06:00 
    DateTime myDate = DateTime.ParseExact(dateTimeFormatted, 
               "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
                return myDate;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                try
                {
                    // This works
                    DateTime myDate2 = DateTime.Parse(dateTimeFormatted);

                    return myDate2;
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {

                    throw;
                }
            }
```

Edit:

This is the final method that I wrote that seems to work flawlessly. Since the method is called shortly after the application generates this timestamp, it will just use Datetime.Now if both DateTime.ParseExact and DateTime.Parse fail.

```
public DateTime GetDateTimeFromFormattedString(string dateTimeFormatted)
{
    try
    {
        //test data 2014-11-10T14:49:24-06:00 
        DateTime myDate;
        bool bIsParsed = DateTime.TryParseExact(dateTimeFormatted.Trim(), 
          "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'sszzz", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out myDate);
        if (bIsParsed)
            return myDate;
        else
            bIsParsed = DateTime.TryParse(dateTimeFormatted.Trim(), out myDate);

        if (bIsParsed)
            return myDate;
        else
            return DateTime.Now;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
        return DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

Another edit:

This works too

```
        DateTimeOffset dto;
        bool bIsParsed = DateTimeOffset.TryParseExact(dateTimeFormatted.Trim(), "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz",
                            System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                            DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal, out dto);
        if (bIsParsed)
            return dto.DateTime;
```

Comment: Side note: use `TryParseExact` and `TryParse` instead of catching exceptions.

Comment: [The code you provided works for me](http://ideone.com/ctM8IJ).

Comment: Yeah, this works here as well. Seeing as you're from the US I doubt it's some exotic culture setting so I can't help but assume it is something unrelated to this.

Comment: @Jeroen that's what `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` is for, it makes the parse method culture-agnostic. This code should not fail on any regional setting, as those are ignored.

Comment: Can you please stop using these single quotes? It doesn't effect anything since you using `InvariantCulture`.

Comment: Yes, but it does still work with them in.

Comment: @gmlacrosse It works without them also as you wrote in your last example `:)` What I try to say, ssing single quote or not is not the point here.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding quotes around specific characters in your format string:

```
DateTime myDate = DateTime.ParseExact(dateTimeFormatted, 
               "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'sszzz", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
```

Comment: You're welcome. Already hit my head against a wall on this issue in the past :)

Comment: In what cases this is necessary?

Comment: There are a set of characters (which I can't exactly remember, I'm sure '/' character is one of these) who are treated not literally but as a culture-dependent date or time separator. So, let say you put a date in this format "MM/dd/yyyy", your server could expect an input string in a different format, eg. "01-20-1990" depending on culture. To avoid errors, whenever I am dealing with predefined date formats, I always put quotes around specific characters and separators.

Comment: That's not the point since OP uses `InvariantCulture`. Single quotes doesn't do anything here.

Comment: @SonerGönül I know, but nonetheless I faced the same issu in the past while running the code on different machines (and different cultures, evidently). Using the quotes worked like a charm to me. And it seems it's working in this case too, looking at the first comment.

Comment: @LittleSweetSeas Single quotes make them a _literal string delimiter_. In this case, **that doesn't effect anything**. That's why your answer seems not helpful at all.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly why it worked but as soon as I put in single quotes, it stopped throwing the first Exception on DateTime.ParseExact

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not throw `FormatException`. But I wish it can..

First of all, don't use [`"zzz"` custom format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#zzzSpecifier) on `DateTime` parsing. It is not recomended. Since a `DateTime` does not store *any* [UTC Offset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) value, there is no point to use it.

From documentation;

> With DateTime values, the "zzz" custom format specifier represents the
>   signed offset of the local operating system's time zone from UTC,
>   measured in hours and minutes. It does not reflect the value of an
>   instance's DateTime.Kind property. For this reason, the "zzz" format
>   specifier is not recommended for use with DateTime values.

If your string have offset part, would be better to parse it to [`DateTimeOffset`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.aspx) instead of a `DateTime`.

Since you use [`DateTimeStyles.None`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.aspx), this will parse your string as a `Local` time. That means it adds your current time zone offset value to you result.

For example, I live in [Turkey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turkey) and now time zone is `UTC +02:00` in here. That's why if I use `DateTimeStyles.None` as you did, result's time part will be `22:49:24` not `20:49:24`.
If I use `DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal`, it will be `20:49:24`.

Here a `DateTimeOffset` parsing;

```
string s = "2014-11-10T14:49:24-06:00";
DateTimeOffset dto;
if(DateTimeOffset.TryParseExact(s, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz",
                                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal, out dto))
{
    Console.WriteLine(dto.DateTime) // 10/11/2014 20:49:24
}
```